# What is up with [tag:plugin]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm looking at https://vi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12622, which suggests some usage for [plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin). I wasn't sure what the tag was being used for, so I hovered and clicked on it.

Hovering shows "30 questions," but when I click the tag I only find one ([Unreadable characters in command section and Quickfix window](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26961/10604), dupe).

If it's really one duplicate, we might be able to just get rid of the tag; on the other hand, if there are 30 questions, I want to find them so we can build consensus on the tag's use (e.g., possible to be an expert in the `:help plugin` system—when they load, etc.—but I would avoid using it for generic plugins or plugin management).

Comment: Some of these questions should be retaggged to [tag:plugin-system], and for others it should be removed. I wouldn't be a fan of creating an alias for this one as it gives the impression that asking for plugins is on-topic, which it's not (although people here usually aren't super-pedantic about immediately closing questions just for this, which is good, I'm not a huge fan of "please find me a plugin"-questions; almost all of them can be rephrased to "how do I do X?")

Comment: @MartinTournoij thanks for the input. I'll have to review the suggested edits to the tag carefully, and possibly go through the questions before doing so, which was my plan. I just don't have immediate time for it :)

Comment: I retagged all questions except three which are off-topic; there are no good tags for those, and they should probably be closed + roomba'd eventually (which will nuke the tag).

Comment: @MartinTournoij closed. Thanks for your recent efforts here; any impetus in particular ?

Comment: There's probably a case for making a generic canonical "How can I get autocompletion in Vim?" question btw, or something along those lines, similar to [How do I install a plugin in Vim/vi?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/613/51); maybe also one for templates/snippets. The answers for those don't even need to be plugins (you can use abbreviations as simple snippets, for example).

Comment: Just don't have anything better to do 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the 'Frequent' tab selected (because the last time you visited a question list, you selected this tab, and the system remembers it):

[image]

When you click the ['Newest' tab](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin?tab=Newest) (or 'Active'), you'll see all 30 questions:

[image]